# Javascript setAttribute in IE9

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer-9, setattribute

So I'm trying to make a table hidden when the webpage opens but when a  is clicked it should show but I'm having problems with IE9. I read that IE8 and below do not support setAttribute and my webpage seems to work correctly with Firefox. Here is the code, just wondering if anyone could help me out:

```
<h1 onclick="myFunction()">Show Sitemap</h1>

<table id="myInput" style="visibility:hidden;" width="100%" height="50%">
<tr><td><p>Test</p></td></tr>
</table>

<script>
function myFunction()
{
document.getElementById("myInput").setAttribute("style","visibility:visible;"); 
};
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using

```
function myFunction()
{
    document.getElementById("myInput").style.visibility = "visible"; 
};
```

instead, as IE is more compatible with this.
Fiddle:http://jsfiddle.net/E396D/

I tried this in IE10 with compatibility mode on and it worked (the original didn't).